# How does shielding work?

Tags: solar-2

Sometimes, a shield pops around my main star.  I'm sure it has something to do with life planets around it that generate their own shield, but how does it work exactly ?  What are the requirements to obtain an energy shield around a star ?  Also, will it work the same for all the stars (small, larger, etc) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All types of stars can become shielded. A shield will form around your star(s) if your system has a tech level of 6 or greater. The system tech level is determined by

```
Number of life planets + Total level of planets
```

The level of a planet can be determined by the number of sections lit up in the ring just under the surface of the planet.

[image]

This planet is at level zero, as all four bars are greyed out, but because it is still a life planet, it would contribute one level to the system's tech level.

This means that while one planet cannot provide a high enough tech level to shield your star, two planets, if they have a high enough level, can do so. Just getting six life planets is also enough to shield your star.